# Keybord shortcut for scrolling tootlip in Jupyter-lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

In Jupyter Lab, if your cursor is on a function and you press
Shift+Tab you get the tooltip to appear.
Is there a shortcut for scrolling over the tooltip instead of using the mouse?